# ECLIPSE RCP app: editing and updating a table viewer

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, swt

I made the table viewer editable by adding setEditingSupport to the columns. But that seem to be not enough. How to access the modified fields if I want to save them in the DB?
What is available to me is only the original fields.
I have a toolbar icon called 'save' to save all my changes in the current row. But that is not available to me. Should I use cell Modifier? How to use that?

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your `EditingSupport`'s `setValue` method.